# How to print from Android webview and insert an SDK to your android Studio project

Tags: android, printing, webview, sdk

I m new to android(java) dev so please bear with me if my questions are pretty stupid, please guys i have a PHP web based platform, i need to put this platform on a `webview` (that was done) but also i need to able to print from the `webview` as an android app too on a selling terminal ( telpo tps 390), the provider gave the SDK but I m not able to use it on the Android Studio. [here is SDK Link](https://mega.nz/#!dJhVkbqR!FSOc2EAziudL-n4KCWUkFE-40Ijy7oeQUeoScG0O8-A), can you help guys please, below my `webview` code

```
package com.example.oussemabeygahar.webvoucher;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView webView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setSupportZoom(false);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webView.loadUrl("https://mobile.bountou1x2.com");
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setSupportZoom(false);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It Much Easer to integrate on android Than a webview since telpo TPS390 need to read the libraries on your app first to be able to print

Comment: Hi, i was able to find a solution i just capture the webview url when printing and then get the strings and print them